# drop down list using backgrid?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, backgrid

I want to create a drop down list in a table cell using backgrid.js

I am creating the following column:

```
{ name: "priority",
    label: "Priority",
    cell: Backgrid.SelectCell.extend({
      // It's possible to render an option group or use a
      // function to provide option values too.
      optionValues: [["one", "a"], ["Two", "b"], ["Three", "c"], ["Four","d"], ["Five", "e"]]
    })
  }
```

But this doesn't render the `Priority` Column. Nor it is displaying the dropdown list.

Help me out, what mistake i am making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var PriorityComboCell = Backgrid.Cell.extend({


template: _.template(

                '<select name="#" id="priority_select"> ' +
                '<option selected="selected"></option>' +
                '<option id="a">One</option>' + 
                '<option id="b">Two</option> ' +
                '<option id="c">Three</option>' +
                '</select>'
            ),
            events: {

            },

            render: function () {

                this.$el.html(this.template({}));
                return this;
            }
    });
```